# Doorkeeper OpenID Connect and user federation with 3rd party IdP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid-connect, doorkeeper

There is an OpenID Connect extension for DoorKeeper - https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-openid_connect Thanks to that DoorKeeper may act like an SSO provider. Is it possible to organize a federation in Doorkeeper with 3rd party IdPs with help of this OpenID Connect extension?